# Return with DB date with time

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I use in Database with type date. I wrote example in field 12.12.2012.
  If execute request in DB example:

```
"Select date From Date" => I get 12.12.2012.
```

I get 12.12.2012.
 I use node.js for send data on client and get 12.12.2012:00:00:00.
Mayby not properly entry in variable callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date you received '12.12.2012:00:00:00' includes the time as well as the date. You can look at it in two parts where '12.12.2012' is the date, and '00:00:00' is the hours:minutes:seconds of the day. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.